# Does "link rel=prerender" work on php included pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, preload

I'm programming an app, just not in java but with html and css(aswell as php & a little javascript of course), but when I use the app it gets reeeeaaly slooww when clicking on the buttons which include/disinclude contant on the site... I am using this code in my head tag of my index.php file:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="index.php?myProfile">
<link rel="prerender" href="index.php?myOptions">
<link rel="prerender" href="index.php?mySavedStyles">
<link rel="prerender" href="index.php?myCamera">
<link rel="prerender" href="index.php?myStyles">
```

Is this even possible to be prerenderd?

This is what the my php line is in the index site where if the "IF" statement is right gets included:

```
<?php if(@$_GET['page'] == 'myProfile'){include 'myProfile.php';}?>
```

And here the actual code being included:

```
 <style>
 #myProfileTop{
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 margin:auto;
 width:100%;
 height:10vh;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
 }
 #myProfileMain{
 left:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 position:absolute;
 height:88%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
 }
 </style>
 <!--###########################  My Profile Site    ##################################-->
 <div id="myProfileTop">
    <div id="profileButtonArea"><div id="profileButtonBox"><img onclick="javascript:location.href='index.php'" id="profileButtonImg" src="<?php  echo $userPath; ?>" /></div></div>
    <div id="optionsButtonArea"><div id="optionsButtonBox"><div onclick="javascript:location.href='?page=myOptions'" id="optionsButtonImg">        </div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="myProfileMain">
         <button onclick="location.href='index.php'">Back</button>
         <button onclick="location.href='php/logout.php'">LOGOUT</button>
    </div>
<!--#################################  END  ########################################-->
```

Comment: YUK. Thats slower than putting all CSS in one file. One CSS file will get loaded once and then cached in the browser. Your code has to be send each time a page uses this code. **Re_Think**

Comment: I had that i the beginning but the same result :/ @RiggsFolly